# Various backend settings don't update on save

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento2.4.4

Under `Stores` -> `Settings` -> `Configuration` -> `Sales` -> `Sales` -> `Minimum order amount` I set `Enable` to `Yes` and `Minimum Amount` to 3000.

When I click `Save Config` the page refreshes, the message **You saved the configuration.** appears and the message **One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Configuration, Page Cache. Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types.** appears, but the `Enable` and `Minimum Amount` values are back to the previous values.

So I go to the cache management, I refresh the invalidated caches, go back to the Configuration page and the options I saved are still back to the old values.

EDIT: I noticed it doesn't work with other settings too. For example with `Stores` -> `Settings` -> `Configuration` -> `Catalog` -> `Catalog` -> `Storefront` -> `Product Listing Sort By`

EDIT 2: I updated the title of this question because it is extended to many options.

Comment: have you checked in DB ? whether values get updated

Comment: Hi Pawan, Do you know the exact names I have to look in DB for these values? Because, for instance, if I look for "minimum" (ignoring case) I don't find anything relevant but a value inside the admin_user table, under the `extra` column inside a specific user entry: "sales_minimum_order":1... Nothing more.

Comment: you can find in `core_config_data` table with path `sales/minimum_order/amount`

Comment: Hi Pawan, the values are not present in the DB. I tried on another instance of the same ecommerce I put on another server and it creates that values in the DB when I set themo from the backend. On the first instance, on the opposite, they are not created.

Comment: I don't know why and how, but the problem is solved. I didn't do anything. Maybe there was a server cache or something similar...